# serealizar y deserializar json despues cargarlo en DataGridView

Tags: json, windows-forms, datagrid

Estoy serializando y quiero deserealizar dentro un datagridview y no encuentro la manera..

```
private void Json()
{
    string sql = @"SELECT 
                        cod,
                        Format(fecha, 'Short Date') as fecha,
                        Format(hora, 'Short Time') as hora,
                        1 as Tipo
                    FROM Registro";


        OleDbDataAdapter d = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        d.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

        List<DatosModel> asis = new List<DatosModel>();
        asis = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DatosModel>>(json);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = asis;
}
```

***Modelo***

```
private class DatosModel
{
    public int cod { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    public DateTime hora { get; set; }
    public int Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

***Mi json:***

```
{"Table":[
{"cod":46897,"fecha":"6/3/2018","hora":"10:34","Tipo":1},{"cod":46929,"fecha":"6/3/2018","hora":"10:35","Tipo":1},{"cod":46972,"fecha":"6/3/2018","hora":"10:35","Tipo":1}
]}
```

Comment: ¿Intentas accediendo a la tabla que esta dentro del Dataset?

Comment: estoy serializando y intento deserializar cadena json

Comment: No me he parado a probarlo, pero por si te sirve de ayuda, veo que lo que estas serializando es un objeto de tipo dataset, pero lo intentas deserializar como datatable y son dos cosas distintintas. Por otro lado creo que el segundo intento falla porque la cadena json no contiene un array, sino un objeto con una propiedad Table que si que contiene un array que seria tu List<RegistroModel>

Comment: De por si un Dataset es un conjunto de Datatables deberias poder coger la informacion de este modo:  DataTable dtValue = ds[0];

Comment: eso es lo que no puedo, me ayudas con un ejemplo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como es cadena ***Json*** te recomiendo que uses todo de tipo cadena(***string***)

**Modelo**

```
private class DatosModel
{
    public int cod { get; set; }
    public string fecha { get; set; }
    public string hora { get; set; }
    public int Tipo { get; set; }
}
```